# Problems with NAs

Tags: r, na

I have a data set like

```
dat
   ejer_id person_alder koen  aar
1        1            9    1 2011
2        2            9    1 2011
3        3            7    1 2011
4        4           94    1 2011
5        5           94    2 2011
6        6           93   NA 2011
7        7           93    1 2011
8        8           91    2 2011
9        9           91    1 2011
10      10           91   NA 2011
```

I count the NAs:

```
isna <- sum(is.na(dat$koen))
```

which gives

```
> isna
   [1] 2
```

I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
 > length( dat$koen[dat$koen == 1] )
[1] 8
```

This should be 6.

> length( dat$koen[dat$koen == 2] )
>       [1] 4

This should be 2.

I can get the following to work:

```
> length( which( dat$koen == 1 ) )
[1] 6
> length( which( dat$koen == 2 ) )
[1] 2
```

My data set is quite large, so I need to know, what I am doing, and I don't understand the difference between these two expressions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try running smaller parts of the code, for example, just run `dat$koen == 1`, then `dat$koen[dat$koen == 1]`, then you should be able to see why `length` says what it does…

Comment: Any logical comparison with `NA` will give you `NA`, e.g.: `NA==1` is `NA`

Answer (score 5):

Remove NA's, following code help you:

`length(na.omit(dat$koen[dat$koen==1]))`

Or same can be done in following way:

`length(dat$koen[which(!is.na(dat$koen[dat$koen==1]))])`

if this wiil not work, explain your issue properly

Answer (score 3):

The thing you should know is that you cannot compare nothing (`NA`) with something (`1` here)., i.e. when the algorithm does this `NA==1`, it does NOT return `FALSE` but it will return `NA`. That is the reason you are getting:

```
 > length( dat$koen[dat$koen == 1] )
[1] 8
```

Try this instead:

```
 > length(dat$koen[dat$koen==1 & !is.na(dat$koen)])
[1] 6
```